# Retrieving parent QTableWidget from its cell widget item

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, qcombobox

I am working on a Project using Qt 5.7 with C++. I am stuck in a weird problem.

I have a `QTableWidget` which contains a `QComboBox` on its one and only cell. Simplified code is as follows.

```
QTableWidget *tab = new QTableWidget();
tab->insertColumn(0);
tab->insertRow(0);
QComboBox *cb = new QComboBox(tab);
cb->addItem("A");
cb->addItem("B");
tab->setCellWidget(0, 0, cb);
```

Now on `currentIndexChanged(int)` signal of the `QComboBox`, I am connecting to a `SLOT` where I am trying to retrieve the pointer of the `QTableWidget` as follows,

```
QComboBox* cb = qobject_cast<QComboBox*>(sender());
QWidget* par = cb->parentWidget();
```

But, I am not getting the same pointer as the actual `QTableWidget`.

I have also tried as follows, but still failed.

```
QComboBox* cb = qobject_cast<QComboBox*>(sender());
QObject *par = cb->parent();
QTableWidget *tab = qobject_cast<QTableWidget *>(par);
```

Can anyone suggest some other way to do it or point out the error in those code segment ?

**Possible Solution Found**

Parent Widget can be retrieved using `cb->parent()->parent()`. Although, this process is not documented, so, not reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the `QTableWidget` is not a direct parent of `QComboBox`, but a grand parent. But even this is an implementation detail and cannot be relied upon, because it is not documented.

A way out could be storing the `QTableWidget` pointer somewhere else.

Comment: Adding a new member variable in my class to store the pointer, will be the last way out. Retrieving the parent from the pointer would be an elegant solution. Can you suggest some other solutions ?

Comment: If you can use C++11 or C++14, use lambdas. Here's how you do it: https://medium.com/genymobile/how-c-lambda-expressions-can-improve-your-qt-code-8cd524f4ed9f#.w0xett5c2. You can capture a pointer to the QTabWidget and do the job then. It is also more type-safe than the `SIGNAL()` and `SLOT()` macros. In short: It makes life so much easier.